# I copy and pasted Navbar example from react-bootstrap docs and receiving error and styling doesn't match docs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I took [this Navbar code example](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/#navbars-mobile-friendly) from the react-bootstrap docs and put it into my component JavaScript file. According to the docs, it should appear in my browser like here:

[image: react-bootstrap docs component example]

...but mine looks like this instead:

[image: my nav component]

In addition, I had to remove the `NavDropdown.Divider` line from the react-bootstrap sample because it was causing:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

I have `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';` in my index.js file.

Does anyone see the problem here?

**My package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "consilio-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5",
    "typescript": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

**My App.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DesignerNavbar from './DesignerNavbar/DesignerNavbar';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <DesignerNavbar></DesignerNavbar>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**My DesignerNavbar.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';

const designerNavbar  = (props) => {
    return (
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <Nav.Link href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
              <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          <Nav>
            <Nav.Link href="#deets">More deets</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link eventKey={2} href="#memes">
              Dank memes
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    )
};

export default designerNavbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your import above. you are using `NavDropdown` but importing `Nav`

Have you tried importing `import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown'`?